# How to set onCLickListner for dynamic ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am working on an android project. I want to add onClick event to listView so that whenever someone clicks on any item in the ListView new fragment showing further details is displayed.I am using Mysql database.

```
package com.example.festipedia_logo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.example.festipedia_logo.Searchpage.LoadAllProducts;


//import com.example.connection.disp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class details1 extends SherlockFragment {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] city;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
EditText b;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.43.185:8080/festipedia/get_all_products.php";
Button a;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "eventname";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;
ListView l;
Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.second);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home2, container, false);

    //  setContentView(R.layout.all_products);
        l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();


        return rootView;
                    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        //  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        //l.setFilterText(id);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] {  R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    l.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Add below ItemClickListener Codes before `return rootView;`

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Do something             
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `OnItemClickListener` and add/replace existing fragment in the container.

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked at" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Also you need not have `runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute` as it is invoked on the ui thread.

You also need to use interface as a call back to the Activity and then add/replace fragment to the container in Activity

Exmple @

[How to send data from fragment to fragment within same fragment activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653359/how-to-send-data-from-fragment-to-fragment-within-same-fragmentactivity/22653391#22653391)

Answer (score 0):

Add ItemClickListener below

```
l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

in function onCreateView();

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something             
    }
});
```